# In python's module schedule, how can I print next run time once after job run?

Tags: python, python-decorators, schedule

After I run pending jobs with Python's [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, I'd like to print once `next job scheduled at {next_job_time}`.

This code prints the message every second which isn't what I want:

```
import schedule
import time

def Job():
    #doing something...

schedule.every(1).hours.do(Job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    print(f"next job scheduled at {schedule.next_run()}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

I thought about using a *decorator* around Job, that prints the message right after job is executed, but when I do this the time printed is that of the current execution and not the next one. I think this because decorators do their stuff before schedule marks the job as completed and updates the jobs list.

Any idea how I can print my message once right after a job completes and still get the correct next_run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found using the decorator seems to produce odd results, so I turn into the loop and display the next run there. The key is compare this 'next run' with the one we displayed the last time and only display if they differ.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

import schedule


def job():
    print("job")


def job2():
    print("job2")


last = None
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(7).seconds.do(job2)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()

    # Display next run, without repeat
    next_run = schedule.next_run()
    if next_run != last:
        print(f"Next run: {next_run}")
    last = next_run

    time.sleep(1)
```

Sample output:

```
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:32:37.449988
job2
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:32:40.449978
job
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:32:44.478158
job2
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:32:50.486706
job
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:32:51.499801
job2
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:32:58.520998
job2
Next run: 2024-03-02 06:33:00.518501
```